# iframe ionic3 app crash when click inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe, ionic3

Hey I am using flipping book url inside iframe:

```
<ng-container>
        <iframe 
                [src]="eUrl"
                id="flipping_book_iframe"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</ng-container>
```

So when I click on download button (coming from the flipping book url )inside the iframe the app crash after some seconds.
But the next and previous slides are working

**Ionic:**

> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.2
>
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular
>
> 3.9.2    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

**Cordova:**

> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
>
> Cordova Platforms: not available

**System:**

> Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
>
> NodeJS            : v8.9.3
>
> npm               : 5.4.2
>
> OS                : Windows 10
>
> I find this inside iframe : but it seems don't work on mobile:
>   publication.pdf
>   it works normal on website.

Comment: Does download work as expected otherwise ?

Comment: yes if i open the link on browser it works fine, and same behaviour on webiste it works normaly, you can see my updated question, about the link that found inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution :
edit htlml iframe to :

```
<ng-container>
    <iframe 
            [src]="eUrl"
            id="flipping_book_iframe"
            #flippingBook
            (load)="onLoadFlippingBook()"
            frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</ng-container>
```

.ts file :

```
 @ViewChild('flippingBook') flippingBookIframe: ElementRef;

onLoadFlippingBook(){
    if(this.flippingBookIframe){
      let iframe = jQuery('#flipping_book_iframe');
      let allAs = iframe.contents().find('a[target=_blank]');
      allAs.on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let url = this.href;
        window.open(url,"_system");
      });
    }
```

at least when u click on download button the pdf opened